# How to get the child of the Ref in cloud messaging Android?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

[image]I am making an android app to send and receive notification using cloud messaging I've tried this to get the child of the ref but none of them worked for me.

I've tried this:

```
const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
//get the user id of the person who sent the message
const senderIdbefore = beforeData.val()
const senderIdafter = afterData.val()
const userid = senderIdbefore.user_id
```

And this:

```
const senderId = change.ref.parent.child('user_id').val();
```

but none of them worked for me.

Here is the code that I am working on:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

 let admin = require('firebase-admin');

 admin.initializeApp();

 exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}').onWrite((change, 
context)  => {

//get the userId of the person receiving the notification because we need 
 to get their token
const receiverId = context.params.userId;
console.log("receiverId: ", receiverId);


const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
//get the user id of the person who sent the message
const senderIdbefore = beforeData.val()
const senderIdafter = afterData.val()
const userid = senderIdbefore.user_id
//  
console.log("senderId: ", senderIdbefore);
console.log("senderId: ", senderIdafter);
console.log("senderId: ", user_id);

//get the message
const message = change.data.child('message').val();
console.log("message: ", message);

//get the message id. We'll be sending this in the payload
const messageId = context.params.messageId;
console.log("messageId: ", messageId);

//query the users node and get the name of the user who sent the message
return admin.database().ref("/users/" + senderId).once('value').then((snap,context) => {
    const senderName = context.child("name").val();
    console.log("senderName: ", senderName);

    //get the token of the user receiving the message
    return admin.database().ref("/users/" + receiverId).once('value').then((snap,context) => {
        const token = context.child("messaging_token").val();
        console.log("token: ", token);

        //we have everything we need
        //Build the message payload and send the message
        console.log("Construction the notification message.");
        const payload = {
            data: {
                data_type: "direct_message",
                title: "New Message from " + senderName,
                message: message,
                message_id: messageId,

            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                        return null
                      })

                      .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                      });
        });

   });
});
```

some of the errors I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined
  at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite 
(/srv/index.js:14:32)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null
  at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite 
(/srv/index.js:17:36)
```

Comment: There's a lot of mention of "android" here, but actually you are just showing Cloud Functions code, which is all backend, nodejs, javascript.  There's not actually any android here.

Comment: The problem here is that you're not checking for null or undefined values where they may be so.  You can't call a method or reference a property of an undefined or null value.  It's similar to NullPointerException in java.  You will have to review the API documentation and check where appropriate.

Comment: yes, but I thought that the android developers should know this and how to code some javaScript.

Comment: Tag questions based on the technologies used in the question itself, not based on who you think should be aware of the technologies.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes your right but I think I got null when I get the wrong value.

Comment: Since you're not showing the data in the database, or showing any log output from your function that illustrates the actual values, there's not much we can do here.  We don't have enough context to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks!, I'll post the picture of the database

Comment: You should also explain the change to the database that causes the function to execute, what you expect to happen, and what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not much of a web developer but I wrote some cloud functions in few of my apps. So what I see wrong here is `(snap,context)` is not the signature of `once()` (I am not completely sure). Maybe that's the reason it is getting null value. You should change it to `snap`(or whatever, say snapshot) and `context.child("name").val()` to `snap.child("name").val()` etc and see if it works.

Also, I wrote a similar script for my chatting app, you can check it [here](https://github.com/azizur-rehman/SSTalk/blob/master/Cloud%20Script/index.js)

Comment: thank! you are right and I also faced another problem by I fixed it also

Comment: @MohammedHemaid So your issue is resolved? Would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

let admin = require('firebase-admin');

 admin.initializeApp();

 exports.sendNotification = 
 functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}').onWrite((change, context)  
 => 
{

//get the userId of the person receiving the notification because we need to get 
their token
const receiverId = context.params.userId;
console.log("receiverId: ", receiverId);
```

Here I used "after" to get the user_id from the message,
instead of change.after.ref.parent.child here is the correct code

```
const senderId = change.after.child('user_id').val();
console.log("senderId: ", senderId);

//get the message
const message = change.after.child('message').val();
console.log("message: ", message);

//get the message id. We'll be sending this in the payload
const messageId = context.params.messageId;
console.log("messageId: ", messageId);

//query the users node and get the name of the user who sent the message
return admin.database().ref("/users/" + senderId).once('value').then((snap,context) 
    => {
    const senderName = snap.child("name").val();
            console.log("senderName: ", senderName);

    //const senderName = context.child("name").val();
    //console.log("senderName: ", senderName);

    //get the token of the user receiving the message
    return admin.database().ref("/users/" + 
     receiverId).once('value').then((snap,context) => {
        const token = snap.child("messaging_token").val();
        console.log("token: ", token);

        //we have everything we need
        //Build the message payload and send the message
        console.log("Construction the notification message.");
        const payload = {
            data: {
                data_type: "direct_message",
                title: "New Message from " + senderName,
                message: message,
                message_id: messageId,

            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                        return null
                      })

                      .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                      });
        });

      });
 });
```